# Shadow at top side of UIView only

Tags: swift, uikit, shadow

How can I remove shadow from bottom side of my view?
This is code for my shadowView:

```
class ShadowViewWhite: UIView {

init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    backgroundColor = .white
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.65, alpha: 0.9).cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowRadius = 40
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -12)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

[image: screenShot]

That's how it looks so far. I need shadow to be only at the top side of my view.

Comment: can you show an image of what you desire ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I don't want to have any shadow effect below my white view so space under white view should be also white

Comment: Add an image of a view that is not connected to the edges of the screen

Answer (score 1):

A combination of reducing the `shadowRadius` and `shadowOffset` should help you. I have attached my code below which should help you.

```
class ShadowViewWhite: UIView {
    
    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.65, alpha: 0.9).cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowRadius = 20
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -40)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

This code will produce the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `shadowRadius` property. Ex:

```
layer.shadowRadius = 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lower values of shadow radius can help. You can try using shadowRadius = 20.